# How to change radius of rounded rectangle in Photoshop

Tags: iphone, adobe-photoshop, icons

At this point, I'm thinking of just using CSS 3, esp. since I'm a programmer, but I'd like to do this with Photoshop because I think it's nicer since I'm working with images anyway, among other reasons...

Before I move on, my first question is:
Is there a place like SuperUser for designers (or for Photoshop-like or questions)?

#### What I Want:

I want the icons on http://www.mattdipasquale.com/ to look like those on http://about.me/mattdipasquale. [About.me](http://about.me) has an outdated Twitter icon and does not have icons for [GitHub](http://github.com), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), etc. So, although I like the look of their icons, I want to be able to create these icons myself instead of using their versions.

#### What I Have:

I have different iphone icons, like the [Facebook iPhone icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQAs6.jpg), [Twitter iPhone icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf52L.jpg), etc., that I got from [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8), using Firebug to find the URL of the background image. I opened them up in Photoshop and pressed option + command + i to reduce the image size to 32px x 32px with Bicubic Sharper (best for reduction). I now have a square icon layer.

#### Closing the Gap:

In addition to the icon layer, I want to have a [clipping-mask layer](http://www.elated.com/articles/creating-and-using-photoshops-clipping-masks/) that will apply the 5px rounded-corners, 1px stroke, and 1px bevel. (*Note: I just want to apply effects to the edges of the icon because the gloss and other effects are already encoded in the [iTunes image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf52L.jpg). Also, I'm just guessing about the pixel values, but I want it to look good, like the icons on about.me.*)

**What settings should I use for the blend options to make the icons look good, like iphone icons or those used by about.me?**

#### Why a Clipping Mask?

The reason I want to use a clipping mask is that I want ease of reproducibility. I want to be able to apply the same styling to other square icon layers by simply replacing the square icon layer and then saving for web. If there is a better way to achieve such ease of reproducibility, please suggest it. I've seen [Photoshop iPhone icon templates](http://blog.cocoia.com/2010/iphone-4-icon-psd-file/), but I couldn't figure out how to use them with my own images.

Comment: I'm not sure if Super User would be a good fit for this kind of question.

Comment: or http://photo.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You can create a rounded rectangle vector mask in photoshop quite easily

- long hold the rectangle tool, select
  the rounded rectangle tool
- set the radius in the options bar
  along the top.
- vector shapes don't snap to pixels so
  to force it you need to set up a
  ruler for each border of your 32x32
  image, draw your rectangle
- right click on the vector mask (not
  just the vector mask layer), choose
  'rasterize vector mask'
- with the mask selected, go to
  image/adustments/invert

now you can the colour of your mask, add your stroke etc.